# CMake: find_file() does not search recursively

Tags: cmake, arduino, toolchain

I'm trying to use the [arduino-cmake](https://github.com/queezythegreat/arduino-cmake) framework but my Arduino-SDK is not recognized correctly. Searching for the cause I found the following:

```
        find_file(${PLATFORM}_BOARDS_PATH
            NAMES boards.txt
            PATHS ${PLATFORM_PATH}
            DOC "Path to Arduino boards definition file.")
```

where `${PLATFORM}_BOARDS_PATH` expands to `ARDUINO_BOARDS_PATH-NOTFOUND`.
`PLATFORM_PATH` correctly points to `/opt/local/arduino-1.8.7/hardware/arduino` and inside you can find `avr/boards.txt`.

So everything seems to be Ok, right?

Changing `PATHS` inside the `find_file()` command to `${PLATFORM_PATH}/avr` gives the right result - so it looks like `find_file` does not search recursively.

What do I do wrong? `arduino-cmake` seems to be working for others so I guess there must be a solution to this without altering paths like this..

Comment: This is intended behaviour that `find_file` doesn't search recursively. Note, that [cmake/Platform/Arduino.cmake](https://github.com/queezythegreat/arduino-cmake/blob/master/cmake/Platform/Arduino.cmake) explicitly describes what is a **platform directory** (which is specified by `PLATFORM_PATH` variable), see the line `# register_hardware_platform(HARDWARE_PLATFORM_PATH)` and below.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tsyvarev pointed out, `find_file()` and `find_path()` do not search recursively. In many cases, you can substitute these commands with the `file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)` command (see more details [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html)).

In your example, you could write something like:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE ${PLATFORM}_BOARDS_PATH boards.txt)
```